# MySQL JOIN Query Optimization on two LARGE Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to optimize this join query on 2 large tables. Table1 is 260k rows and Table2 is 1.8m rows. MySQL Explain shows that they're using indexes but each load is 4-5 seconds each which is not going to work for my needs.

```
SELECT table1.col2
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1.col1=table2.col1
 WHERE table2.col2>=table1.col2 
   AND table.col1 NOT IN (1,2,3,4,...)
```

Basically I need to make sure that table2 has a higher or equal col2 than table1 and then output the col2 that table1 has. Also the NOT IN will remove any already viewed rows from table1 in a list by col1. (However, the main issue for the query performance though seems to come from the greater than equal to argument)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could introduce a new table where most of the data you're selecting is pre-calculated. However.. that would only be effective if it consists of static data.

Comment: @Xorifelse unfortunately the table2 data is constantly changing while table1 data is more static it also changes occasionally.

Comment: What indexes are defined? And how many rows does this query return?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel there an index on table1.col1, one on table1.col2 and one on table2.col1. It only needs to grab 12-24 rows with the limit in place.

Comment: For this query you need a composite index on `table2(col1, col2)`.